# Search using column name and term

Tags: 2010, search

I would like to be able to set up the search so that users can search by a column name and term (CustomColumnName:baseball). I have set up a managed property and it has gone through a full crawl. Though when I put the columnname:term in the search box nothing comes back. Not sure what I am missing. Any and all help is welcome.

SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time this is because

- you do not see items with the new values. Try searching with the search content access account.
- there is no item which fills the new property. Fill one and do a full crawl.
- Your crawled property to managed property mapping is wrong. Check if there is the correct crawled property assigned to the new managed property.
- You did not wait until the full crawl is complete and the zero result is cached for a short period. Go try again.